# cant get HTML5 canvas to work on any browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have just started learning how to draw on using HTML5 canvas, I'm trying to make a simple square but all I get is a blank screen, I don't get errors in the chrome console either

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Drawing to a canvas</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
window.onload = draw;
function draw() 
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,200,0,1)";

ctx.fillRect = (36,10,50,50);

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="300">
This text is displayed if your browser 
does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

This seems quite simple but it just won't work for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error is the one Elon pointed out, but you are using the `fillRect` wrong as well:

```
ctx.fillRect = (36,10,50,50);
```

should be:

```
ctx.fillRect(36,10,50,50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please debug before asking for help!

You've got syntax error because you forgot about `{` after function name.

```
function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,200,0,1)";

    ctx.fillRect(36,10,50,50);
}
```

Comment: Your second statement is not true. Functions declared this way are available anywhere in the scope. Javascript is not some kind of retarded C++

Comment: @Adassko Right, but fact that you don't understand something doesn't mean that it's retarded. It's just too complicated for you :)

Comment: Well, I guess your thoughts are too complicated for me ;)

Comment: the missing { was a result of a delete key slip when asking the question, thank you for the help